# I want to frequently change the system time and date on Windows, so that data collection occurs in my database

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

This is how I do it on Linux: First I generate all the required dates using a Java program. I store the output in a "time.txt" in the format "16 Sep 2013 10:44:39". And then I run a shell script which uses this "time.txt" to get inputs and set the system time & date accordingly. I need the Windows equivalent for the same. I cannot manually change it 317 times.

This is my shell script:

```
for((i=1; i<=317; i++))
do
niks=`sed -n ''$i'p' time.txt`
echo `date -s "$niks"`
sleep 3;
done
```

By the time this code completes execution, I will have changed the system date and time 317 times, all my data collection tasks will have been completed and my database records will have been populated. The 3 second sleep is for the database trending to occur. Only then can I test a few modules. This is on Linux. Now I need to do the same thing on a Windows system. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you be generating data that is time dependent?  In your environment, can you not generate some dummy data which is like what you would encounter (i.e. is time dependent), but can be generated without having to do all of that work?

Comment: I'm working on a Network Element Management System. Too many tables, large amount of data is required to view meaningful results. I can't go "insert into table values" for everything.

Comment: I need to trigger certain activities that are scheduled to occur in 5-min interval, 15-min interval, 1 hour interval, 4-hour interval, 1 week interval, and 1-month intervals. I could and have done this on Linux using Shell script. I just need to repeat it on Windows (using Batch maybe). That was my request.

Comment: Changing the system clock to generate sample data is a pretty bad way to reach your goal. Having the managed element yield measurements more frequently is probably the easiest approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is the `time` command line tool to change the time on windows.

it is documented here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491015.aspx

and then there is `date`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490889.aspx

Comment: While this may answer the question as posed, the question itself contains at least two major misconceptions about how test data ought be generated.

Comment: i tend to agree that there probably is a better way to test with mock data, but i do not know enough about the original setup to conclude that it is easily possible to feed all involved components some mock data, and that a full end-to-end test is not reasonable. thus i don't think i should withhold this information.

Comment: Agreed; my comment was as much for the OP (perhaps more so) than for you. Your comment does amplify that the question is underspecified.

Comment: @Raam if this answer was helpful, you can upvote it on the left (arrow pointing upwards) (you can upvote as many answers as you like) and accept it as the best answer (the gray check mark that will turn green when clicking).